# Perl - Sort hash for third dimensional array with GROUP by

Tags: perl

In Perl, I have a multi-dimensional hash monthlysale in this form:

```
monthlysale{$year}{$qtr}{itemcode}
```

A sample of this is:

```
monthlysale{2013}{3}{MNB}= is 5
monthlysale{2013}{3}{ABC}= is 24
monthlysale{2013}{3}{CL}= is 336
monthlysale{2013}{3}{XNX}= is 18
monthlysale{2013}{3}{CVG}= is 15
monthlysale{2013}{3}{CTP}= is 11
monthlysale{2013}{3}{CPE}= is 86
monthlysale{2013}{4}{MNB}= is 47
monthlysale{2013}{4}{ABC}= is 60
monthlysale{2013}{4}{CL}= is 39
monthlysale{2013}{4}{XNX}= is 16
monthlysale{2013}{4}{CVG}= is 26
monthlysale{2013}{4}{CTP}= is 19
```

and similar for other years and months, for the list of items.

However, the above is NOT in the mentioned order, instead it is randomly placed for year and quarter.

My requirement is to print a SORTED output, which should be sorted from high sales value to low sales value, but should be grouped by year and quarter.

For example, the desired output should be:

```
monthlysale{2013}{3}{CL}= is 336
monthlysale{2013}{3}{CPE}= is 86
monthlysale{2013}{3}{ABC}= is 24
monthlysale{2013}{3}{XNX}= is 18
monthlysale{2013}{3}{CVG}= is 15
monthlysale{2013}{3}{CTP}= is 11
monthlysale{2013}{3}{MNB}= is 5


monthlysale{2013}{4}{ABC}= is 60
monthlysale{2013}{4}{MNB}= is 47
monthlysale{2013}{4}{CL}= is 39
monthlysale{2013}{4}{CVG}= is 26
monthlysale{2013}{4}{CTP}= is 19
monthlysale{2013}{4}{XNX}= is 16
```

and so on.

That is...the output should start from the very first available year (first-dimension), circle through quarter values of 1 ,2,3,4 (second-dimension), and list the item code (CL,CPE,ABC, etc. - third dimension) and the array values (336,86, 24...) in the descending order of the array values.

I tried the following code, but

```
foreach $yr (@yeararray) #This array is sorted (2001,2002,2003....)
{
    foreach $qt (@qtrarray) #This array is sorted (1,2,3,4)
    {
        foreach my $name (sort { $monthlysale{$yr}{$qt}{$a} <=> $monthlysale{$yr}{$qt}{$b} or $a cmp $b } keys %monthlysale{$yr}{$qt})
        {
            printf "%-8s %s\n", $name, $monthlysale{$yr}{$qt}{$name};
        }
    }
}
```

But it is returning an error: "`Experimental keys on scalar is now forbidden at script.pl line 111, <DATA> line 1.`"

What am I doing wrong here. and what can be done to get the desired output please?

PS:
Data in CSV form as asked for in the comment:

```
2013,3,MNB,5
2013,3,ABC,24
2013,3,CL,336
2013,3,XNX,18
2013,3,CVG,15
2013,3,CTP,11
2013,3,CPE,86
2013,4,MNB,47
2013,4,ABC,60
2013,4,CL,39
2013,4,XNX,16
2013,4,CVG,26
2013,4,CTP,19
```

Comment: Can you include your data in a form that can just be copy and pasted into a script?

Comment: @Shawn - updated the CSV data in the lower part of the question.

Comment: I meant your multi dimensional hash. Or the arrays your code seems to be using? Your actual data structure.

Comment: `keys %monthlysale{$yr}{$qt}` should be `keys %{$monthlysale{$yr}{$qt}}` I think.

Comment: @ChrisCharley - Thanks. However, this does NOT work. Same error repeats.

Comment: @Aquaholic ChrisCharley's modification _does_ work. If it doesn't, then you're not running the code you posted in your question. Please post your actual code if you want helpful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following piece of code demonstrates how desired output can be generated.

The code consists of two subroutines `read_data` and `print_sorted`

> to *swallow* the data into hash of hashes with `sub read_data`
>
> output sorted hash with `sub print_sorted`
>
> - sort hash by year
> - sort hash by quarter
> - generate new hash where we swap *keys* and *values*
> - sort new hash on keys *amount*
> - output name of the hash *value* and *amount*

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $debug = 0;

my $data = read_data();

say Dumper($data) if $debug;

print_sorted($data);

sub print_sorted {
    my $data = shift;

    for my $year ( sort keys %{$data} ) {
        for my $quarter ( sort keys %{$data->{$year}} ) {
            my @amount = values %{$data->{$year}{$quarter}};
            my @items  = keys %{$data->{$year}{$quarter}};

            my %hash;
            @hash{@amount} = @items;

            for my $amount ( reverse sort {$a <=> $b} keys %hash ) {
                say "sales{$year}{$quarter}{$hash{$amount}} = $amount";
            }

            say '';
        }
    }
}


sub read_data {
    my %data;

    while( <DATA> ) {
        chomp;
        my($y,$i,$s,$a)   = split ',';
        $data{$y}{$i}{$s} = $a;
    }

    return \%data;
}

__DATA__
2013,3,MNB,5
2013,3,ABC,24
2013,3,CL,336
2013,3,XNX,18
2013,3,CVG,15
2013,3,CTP,11
2013,3,CPE,86
2013,4,MNB,47
2013,4,ABC,60
2013,4,CL,39
2013,4,XNX,16
2013,4,CVG,26
2013,4,CTP,19
```

Output

```
sales{2013}{3}{CL} = 336
sales{2013}{3}{CPE} = 86
sales{2013}{3}{ABC} = 24
sales{2013}{3}{XNX} = 18
sales{2013}{3}{CVG} = 15
sales{2013}{3}{CTP} = 11
sales{2013}{3}{MNB} = 5

sales{2013}{4}{ABC} = 60
sales{2013}{4}{MNB} = 47
sales{2013}{4}{CL} = 39
sales{2013}{4}{CVG} = 26
sales{2013}{4}{CTP} = 19
sales{2013}{4}{XNX} = 16
```

Comment: Thanks @PolarBear, Please allow me some time to test this.

Comment: Thanks @PolarBear, Perfect answer, and +1 !